# C++ order of operations and modulus

Tags: c++

How would `25 % 8 - 9 / 2 => -3.5` be interpreted using cmath?

Is it:

```
25% 8 = 1 ;
-9/2 = -4.5
```

Order of operations:

```
1 - 4.5 = -3.5
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"interpreted using cmath"*? cmath is not an interpreter. It is a header in the C++ standard library that declares some math related functions.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: `9/2` is `4` and not `4.5`.

Comment: In addition to @user2079303, the functions defined in `<cmath>` are named functions living in `namespace std`. Basic `int` arithmetic like this is part of the core language.

Comment: @mch , how does 9/2 = 4? Put it in a calculator and the answer will be 4.5

Comment: @user9404879: The division is carried out in integer arithmetic since both arguments are integral types. It's a rule of the language.

Comment: But that's not how real math works.

Comment: @user9404879 No. That's exactly how "real" (as in real world) math works. Remember back in elementary school, when you were first taught division. Mary has 9 sweets. She shares the sweets evenly between her 2 friends. How many did the firends get? They each get **4**, and there is 1 left over. That's integer division.

Comment: "Computer math is to math how computer music is to music." Math abstractions and rules are interpreted in various manners depending on how the language designers implemented the various libraries and core APIs. This is the case for "floored division" for example.

Comment: @user9404879: Let's use the standard Desk Calculator to do integer division: `dc <<<'9 2 / p'`.  That gives **`4`**, as expected.

Answer (score 3):

This is not about order of operations, and it's not about cmath. It's about **precedence**, and that is hardwired into the **grammar** of C++. The basic rule that applies here is that multiplication and division bind more tightly than addition and subtraction, so an expression like `a*b+c*d` is treated as if it were written `(a*b)+(c*d)`. That is, the product of a and b is added to the product of c and d. It does **not** mean that c is added to the product of a and b, and then the result is multiplied by d.

To apply that to the example here (keep in mind that `%` is just another form of division):

```
25 % 8 - 9 / 2
```

is treated as if it had been written

```
(25 % 8) - (9 / 2)
```

`25 % 8` has the value 1, and `9 / 2` has the value 4 (not 4.5; 9 and 2 are integers, so this is integer division). The result is `1 - 4`, which is `-3`.

Comment: You don't mind my cheeky edit? Thank you for taking the time to answer this.

Comment: @Bathsheba -- thanks for the clarifying edit.

Comment: And a grace note to the edit by @Bathsheba -- every programming language that I know of interprets arithmetic expressions this way.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is just to try it. Other than that, you can look at precedence tables like [this one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) to see where operators are relative to each other. In this case, since the `%` operator has higher precedence than the `-` operator, it is performed first, then the `/` since it also has higher precedence, so you would end up with `(25 % 8) - (9 / 2)`as an equivalent expression. Since these are all integers, the operations will occur with integer operations, and give a result of `-3`.

Comment: But that is incorrect. As I said in the OP, it's (1) - (4.5) = -3.5

Comment: @user9404879 Nope, this is correct -9/2 is -4 in C++ https://www.ideone.com/y9KibZ

Answer (score -1):

Cmath declares only set of functions to compute common mathematical operations and transformations nothing else. Operators priority are independent on libs, like cmath.

But u probably looking for table of operators priority: [Documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

In your example is something like this **(25 % 8) - (9 / 2)** => **-3**

Comment: `(9 / 2)` is not `3.5` or a `float`/`double`

Comment: Yeach you are right

Comment: @NathanOliver: Well, it would be `4.5` or `4.5f` obviously. But the statement here is about `1 - (9/2) ` which explains the `-3`. The reason `float/double`  makes no sense is that `%`  is the **integer** remainder operation

Comment: @msalters it's integer division.  The result is just 4 as an `int`